# Создание и обучение нейросети

Tags: c#, нейронные-сети

Есть несколько параметров в csv файле записанных через `,`. Есть пара тысяч строк с этими параметрами и крайним параметром `0` или `1`. Нужно обучить сеть так, чтобы после обучения она определяла крайний параметр по предыдущим. Есть ли какие-то готовые библиотеки, желательно для C# где можно реализовать эту задачу? И есть ли какой-то паттерн, алгоритм как это делать?

---

**Дополнение:**

Если взять мою задачу, то есть *.csv файл, в котором лежат такие параметры как *длительность* (int), *страна-производитель* (str), *оригинальный язык* (str), *возрастное ограничение* (string), *принадлежность к жанру*
 (bool), *путь к постеру* (str). Все это фильмы. Нужно определить: является ли фильм комедией или нет. Картинку я сразу отложил в виду сложности работы с ней. Думаю пока работать только с жанрами и по ним смотреть. Может есть алгоритм, который сможет работать с этими неоднородными параметрами? Или вычислять вероятность по отдельности.

Comment: Ну в принципе задача не сложная. Можно не использовать какие-либо сторонние средства. Что за строки в файле и есть ли реальная зависимость между последним параметром и предыдущими?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы описываете классическую постановку задачи *бинарной классификации*. Есть набор параметров **X** и меток **Y** (это, как Вы выразились, крайние значения *1* и *0*), которые связаны зависимостью **Y = F(X)**. Зависимость неизвестна. Но если выборка большая, то можно попытаться построить и алгоритм **A**, такой, что **||A-F|| -> min** на любом примере, в т.ч. который не входит в изначальный набор.

В силу того, что Вы не описываете деталей своей задачи, смею предположить, что нейронные сети Вам ни к чему. Лучше попробуйте использовать [случайные леса](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_MachineLearning_DecisionTrees_RandomForest.htm). Для их настройки Вам не нужно задавать никаких специфических параметров. Работают они, как правило, не хуже нейронных сетей, которые Вам придётся настраивать.

Другим простым решением является [логистическая регрессия](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_Statistics_Models_Regression_LogisticRegression.htm). Этот алгоритм также не требует глубокой настройки и может быть использован практически из коробки.

Для того, чтобы обучить модель, Вам необходимо разделить данные *(X, Y)* на 2 части в соотношении, например, *70%* и *30%*. Данные следует предварительно перемешать, дабы исключить влиение скрытых зависимостей. Далее обучите выбранную модель на большем поднаборе.

После обучения следует протестировать Вашу модель на меньшем поднаборе данных. Т.е. для каждого **X** получить ответ модели **Y*** и сравнить его с имеющимся результатом **Y**. Качество построенного алгоритма можно оценить так:

*(Число правильных ответов, предсказанных алгоритмом на меньшей выборке) / (Число всех примеров меньшей выборки)*

Для более детальной информации по Вашему вопросу, необходимо понимать, с какими данными Вы имеете дело.

---

**Дополнение:**

Вы можете запихнуть все свои данные в модель. Лучше использовать *Random Forest*. В таком случае, Вам не понадобится их подготавливать. Главное, чтобы они были числовыми. Пусть длительность -- первый признак. Страна-производитель -- второй (его необходимо закодировать числом, т.е. найти все возможные строки, которые есть у вас и каждой уникальной поставить в соответствие число). Оригинальный язык -- аналогично предыдущей фичи (фича от features -- признак). Возрастное ограничение необходимо представить числом. Принадлежность жанру необходимо представить булевой переменной. Путь к постеру является неинформативным признаком и может быть исключён, поскольку он вряд ли может повлиять на информацию о фильме. Картинки я Вам советую не использовать, поскольку для их использования, вероятно, потребуется очень большая выборка, а их обработка сложна. После такой обработки, пихайте всё в RandomTree с параметрами по умолчанию. Можно попробовать их бездумно покрутить. Скорее всего получите лучший результат. Руками выберите лучший.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за такой развернутый ответ. Если взять конкретно мою задачу, то есть .csv файл, в котором лежат такие параметры как длительность(int), страна производитель(str), оригинальный язык(str), возрастное ограничение(string), принадлежит ли жанру[21](bool), путь к постеру(str). Все это фильмы, нужно в конечном итоге определить является ли фильм комедией. Картинку я сразу отложил в виду сложности работы с ней.Думаю пока работать только с жанрами и по ним смотреть. Может есть алгоритм, который сможет работать с этими неоднородными параметрами. Или вычислять вероятность по отдельности...

Comment: @Max Попробуйте то, что я описал, для начала. В силу того, что у Вас нет представления о том, как решаются подобные задачи. Пожалуй, это будет одним из самых адекватных решений. Если качество окажется неудовлетворительным, задайте ещё один вопрос с описанием того, что Вы делали и чего хотелось бы получить.

Comment: Этот метод будет работать только с однотипными данными `принадлежит ли жанру[21](bool)` или можно как-то прикрутить и остальные параметры?

Comment: @Max не понял вопроса.

Comment: Вы можете представить запихнуть все свои данные в модель. Лучше использовать *Random Tree*. В таком случае, Вам не понадобится их подготавливать. Главное, чтобы они были числовыми. Пусть *длительность* -- первый признак. *Страна-производитель* -- второй (его необходимо закодировать числом, т.е. найти все возможные строки, которые есть у вас и каждой уникальной поставить в соответствие число). *Оригинальный язык* -- аналогично предыдущей фичи (фича от features -- признак). *Возрастное ограничение* необходимо представить числом. *Принадлежность жанру* необходимо представить булевой переменной.

Comment: *Путь к постеру* является неинформативным признаком и может быть исключён, поскольку он вряд ли может повлиять на информацию о фильме. Картинки я Вам советую не использовать, поскольку для их использования, вероятно, потребуется очень большая выборка, а их обработка сложна. После такой обработки, пихайте всё в RandomTree с параметрами по умолчанию. Можно попробовать их бездумно покрутить. Скорее всего получите лучший результат. Руками выберите лучший.

Comment: Понял, закодирую все в цифры, картинки исключу и буду пробовать.

Comment: @Max Random Forest, а не Random Tree

Comment: Может вы знаете в чем может быть ошибка? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46515561/exceptions-in-a-random-forest

Comment: @Max как минимум в том, что непонятно, о чём Вы речь ведёте. Как люди должны разобраться в том, чего не видят? Поправьте вопрос, чтобы там был минимально воспроизводимый пример.